# IntelliJ Idea intellisense does not show java.utils.List

Tags: intellij-idea

From a moment on my IntelliJ Idea does not show **java.utils.List** class in Intellisense. This appens ONLY for java.utils.List all other classes are shown.

[image]

Is there a specific settings I inadvertently changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to *Preferences/Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import* and delete `java.util.*` pattern from the Exclude from auto-import and completion list.